# m24512 eeprom IC raspberry pi python

Tags: python, i2c, eeprom

The IC is not working as suggested on official GitHub page

Here is my code:

```
i2cdetect -y 1
```

Shows

> eeprom IC M24512 at 0x50

Python code:

```
import smbus
import time

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

time.sleep(0.5)
print 'write 1 30'
bus.write_i2c_block_data(80, 0, [0x0001, 30])
time.sleep(0.5)
bus.write_i2c_block_data(80, 0, [0x0001])
time.sleep(0.5)
print 'read 1 ', bus.read_byte(80)
time.sleep(0.5)
bus.write_i2c_block_data(80, 0, [0x0002])
time.sleep(0.5)
print 'read 2 ', bus.read_byte(80)
time.sleep(0.5)
bus.write_i2c_block_data(80, 0, [0x0003])
time.sleep(0.5)
print 'read 3 ', bus.read_byte(80)
time.sleep(0.5)

time.sleep(0.5)
print 'write 2 40'
bus.write_i2c_block_data(80, 0, [0x0002, 40])
time.sleep(0.5)
bus.write_i2c_block_data(80, 0, [0x0001])
time.sleep(0.5)
print 'read 1 ', bus.read_byte(80)
time.sleep(0.5)
bus.write_i2c_block_data(80, 0, [0x0002])
time.sleep(0.5)
print 'read 2 ', bus.read_byte(80)
time.sleep(0.5)
bus.write_i2c_block_data(80, 0, [0x0003])
time.sleep(0.5)
print 'read 3 ', bus.read_byte(80)
time.sleep(0.5)

time.sleep(0.5)
print 'write 3 50'
bus.write_i2c_block_data(80, 0, [0x0003, 50])
time.sleep(0.5)
bus.write_i2c_block_data(80, 0, [0x0001])
time.sleep(0.5)
print 'read 1 ', bus.read_byte(80)
time.sleep(0.5)
bus.write_i2c_block_data(80, 0, [0x0002])
time.sleep(0.5)
print 'read 2 ', bus.read_byte(80)
time.sleep(0.5)
bus.write_i2c_block_data(80, 0, [0x0003])
time.sleep(0.5)
print 'read 3 ', bus.read_byte(80)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Output on the terminal:
    write 1 30
    read 1 30
    read 2 30
    read 3 30
    write 2 40
    read 1 40
    read 2 40
    read 3 40
    write 3 50
    read 1 50
    read 2 50
    read 3 50

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: Actually single byte write and read is working fine.. so I had to post this long code to show the problem..